# C# Castle Windsor does not inject NLog instance when using factory

Tags: c#, factory, castle-windsor, nlog

The problem is that when I'm using the LoggingFacility of Windsor.Castle (WC) the ILogger instance is still a NullLogger instance when the class is being created using a custom factory class. Creating instances without a custom factory will set the ILogger as a NLog instance. The instances of the classes are of type `ICam` and registered using an unique name.

NLog is being registered as a logging facility

```cs
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(m => m.LogUsing<NLogFactory>().WithConfig("NLog.config"));
```

Class definitions contain an `NullLogger` instance:

```cs
public ILogger Log { get; set; } = NullLogger.Instance;
```

I'm using this custom factory implementation (bit shortened for readability). It only overrides the `GetComponentName` method to get the correct name so WC can create an instance of the correct class.

```cs
public class CameraTypeFactory : DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector
    {
        protected override string GetComponentName(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
        {
            if (!(arguments?.Length > 0))
            {
                return "Unknown";
            }

            if (!(arguments[0] is ICameraInfo cameraInfo))
            {
                return "Unknown";
            }

            string cameraType = cameraInfo.GetValueOrDefault(CameraInfoKey.DeviceType, "Unknown");

            return cameraType;
        }
    }
```

The factory is being registered as a factory and a ICam instance is registered with the name `cameratypename`. Then an instance is created using the `ICameraFactory` like `ICameraFactory factory.Create(cameraInfo)` where `cameraInfo` implements interface `ICameraInfo`.

```cs
container
    .Register(
        Component
            .For<ICameraFactory>()
            .AsFactory(new CameraTypeFactory())
    )
    .Register(
        Component
            .For<ICam>()
            .ImplementedBy<Camera>()
            .Named("cameratypename")
    );
```

Container is an `IWindsorContainer`. The ICameraFactory is defined as:

```cs
public interface ICameraFactory
{
    ICam Create(ICameraInfo cameraInfo);
}
```

It works, I get an instance of the correct class, but there is no logging instance, it's still a NullLogger although everything is being created using WC. Does the factory class need more overrides or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest put the declaration of Log inside the class definition and instantiation inside the constructor of the class. After that you could call for example Log.Info() inside your methods.
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-.NET-Core-2---Console-application